# Resource for getting agentive noun from verb automatically

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, verbs, resource-request

I am trying to get (in some automated fashion) the agentive noun of a given verb. For instance we have

1. buy, buy**er**
2. sell, sell**er**
3. invest, invest**or**

I was wondering whether there is some resource that contains a mapping of verbs to their agentive nouns. I have looked around a bit in traditional resources like WordNet, VerbNet etc. but have not had any luck yet.

All suggestions are immensely appreciated.

Comment: This question is language-specific (hence off-topic here). It better fits at [ell.se]. In fact, it has been already [asked and answered](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/708/27) there.

Comment: @bytebuster No, it has not. I am asking for NLP resources, not for the rule that governs the alternations.

Comment: If you want a list (rather than a rule, which is too weak to use), then just extract each ...-or word from your dictionary, reconstruct a root and see if that is a verb (but beware of context).